# Flutter error Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1102

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I have a flutter error although i dont have any bugs in code.
This is all error:

```html
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-3.2.0/lib/src/delegate_widget.dart:194:18: Error: Superclass has no method named 'inheritFromElement'.
    return super.inheritFromElement(ancestor, aspect: aspect);
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-3.2.0/lib/src/provider.dart:259:19: Error: The method 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
 - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType'.
        ? context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(type) as InheritedProvider<T>
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-3.2.0/lib/src/provider.dart:260:19: Error: The method 'ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
 - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType'.
        : context.ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType(type)?.widget
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1102

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

[error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uA17N.png)

I downgrade the version to 1.12.15 and steal nothing

Comment: Please check out our [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) so you can [edit] your question to make it more readable. Hint: put code fences around build output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue after restarting my PC.

try any of the following:

upgrade your dependencies in your `pubspec.yaml`

or

try flutter `flutter clean` then `flutter run`

lastly, if it didn't work you've to delete the flutter src folder in
`Script 'C:\src\flutter` and reinstall it again

make sure the path you created your flutter project have no spaces.

Comment: Could you tell me where you can find the src folder in ubuntu? Is it the directory where the flutter sdk is extracted?

Comment: flutter doctor -v
The first line will show the install path...

Answer (score 0):

delete your flutter folder and reinstall it. I faced this problem and overcame such this way.

Answer (score 0):

The most valid solution is to delete your `Sdk` And download New one